# Using react-apollo, how to define 2 mutations in the same component with TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, apollo, react-apollo

Using the following [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/1369) I am able to make one mutation work with **Typescript**. But I did not find a way to use 2 mutations in the same component.

There is only one `mutate()` function in `this.props`.

How must we typed our component to make it understand the `name` options passed to graphql?

```
graphql<ContainerProps, {}, string, ContainerProps>(gql`... `, { name: 'deleteData' });
graphql<ContainerProps, {}, string, ContainerProps>(gql`...`, { name: 'createData' });
```

EDIT:
If the 2 mutations have the same parameter name (a `string` named `id` for example), do we really need to wrap these parameters in an explicit type?

EDIT 2:
I have this exception when I declare the 2 mutations with `{ name: 'xxx' }`:

> TypeError: _this.props.mutate is not a function

If I declare only one mutation (without the name option), it's working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the link provided by Miro Lehtonen here is what's working for me.

```
type MutationProps = {
    create: MutationFunc<IResponse, ICreateVariables>;
    delete: MutationFunc<IResponse, IDeleteVariables>;
};

type ContainerProps = OtherQueryProps & MutationProps;

const withCreate =
    graphql<ContainerProps, IResponse, ICreateVariables, ContainerProps>(
        CreateMutation,
        {
            // tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
            props: ({ mutate, ...rest }): any => ({
                ...rest,
                create: mutate
            })
        });
```

The code is the same for the delete mutation.

The code is working but I don't like having `any` in it. I did not find a way to correctly type the props and I don't think I return the correct type (though it's working fine). Any suggestions are very welcome (on how to remove the `any`).

Answer (score 0):

The default name for a mutation would be `mutate` which you can access through `props.mutate`. If you want to have more mutations in the same component, you need to give them names such as `deleteData` and `createData`. These are accessible through `props.deleteData` and `props.createData`.

A good practice is to name all mutations, just to make your code easier to read. As a generic name, `mutate` is not very descriptive.

Comment: Yes that how it works. I already used the `name` option, but it's not working. How do you do it with **Typescript**?

Comment: Did you try the solution mentioned here yet?
 https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/1378